# "PostProcess" and "Tolerance" in DifferentialEvolution?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, options, documentation

What is `"postprocess"` option in `DifferentialEvolution` method (for instance when using `NMaximize`)?

What does it do when `"Automatic"`?

How can I set it differently for it to suite best my function?

Also what exactly is `"Tolerance"` option? What does that number mean?

Comment: FWIW, `"PostProcess"` may be `FindMinimum`, `"KKT"`, or `"InteriorPoint"`. The meanings are pretty obvious. `Automatic` means `"KKT"` followed by `"InteriorPoint"` only if the first attempt didn't work out. I don't know what the proper interpretation of the numerical value of `"Tolerance"` is, though.

Comment: Have you already read through [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html), by any chance?

Comment: Yes I've read that. Yet it doesn't answer to my questions.